# What does **pulled at** mean here?

Tags: meaning

What does **pulled at** mean here?

> Meg **pulled at** him. ‘Mrs Whatsit said for us to go on into the
>   town.’
>
> another piece:
>
> ‘Come on.’ Meg **pulled at** them. How many times was it she had urged
>   them on? ‘Let’s go find father. He’ll be able to explain it all to
>   us.’

A Wrinkle in Time by Madeleine L'Engle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the usual meaning of pull.

As a phrase, [pull at](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+at) means "tug something" or metaphorically "demand attention".  It is a matter of context or interpretation whether Meg was actually pulling, or only telling them to move.